# Spring JPA is auto inserting Entity before call to save. How can this be prevented?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot

I've got a Spring Boot application with numerous entities configured via JPA annotations.  For new entities of a specific type I run several queries to determine if old entries exist based on a date field.  That part works fine.  However, I've not called save() on the repository at any point with the target object.  While the select queries are executing I what seems to be automated flush...

```
2014-11-06 12:05:46.617 DEBUG 5070 [clientInboundChannel-10] --- org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue     : Executing identity-insert immediatel
2014-11-06 12:05:52.647 DEBUG 5070 --- [boundChannel-10] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into target_object_table... 
2014-11-06 12:05:52.647 DEBUG 5070 [clientInboundChannel-10] --- org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into ftarget_object_table...
```

The problem is since I didn't initiate this flush my version of the object still has an ID of 0.  Therefore at a later point in the @Transaction I call repository.save(targetObject) and end up with two saved in the database.

In researching via google it seems like two things might fix this but I'm not 100% sure how to configure them with "spring-boot" / "jpa".

1) I am guessing that since my object has @Entity notation it is automatically being attached at instantiation time.  Is there any easy way to prevent this?  Do I have to explicitly call detach() on the entity manager?

2) Is there a application.properties setting to change the flush mode to commit or an option on an annotated @Query to change the commit mode at a per query level?

Comment: I think you've got problem with your understanding of transactions, flush and save. In spring declarative transaction mgmt you almost never have to invoke flush, but at the end of transaction boundary (marked by @Transaction -- taking into account parent / child method invocation), Spring transaction management will commit the transaction. Flushing time is often undetermined and you should never have to know when, except it always occur prior to end of transaction

Answer (score 1):

So after some deep investigation and setting breakpoints in the Hibernate insert code I determined I did indeed have two valid requests coming in at the exact same second.  This was not behavior I expected from the web application tier so I had not went down this route of debugging when asking the question.  Because my transactions were not configured to lock on reads both transaction methods could do checks against the DB for an existing entry for a date (not find it and then do an insert).  After fixing the web tier (that is an AngularJS issue) the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

First question)

> I am guessing that since my object has @Entity notation it is automatically being attached at instantiation time.

This is wrong, when you create a new Class that is annotated by `@Entity` it does NOT automatic become an JPA(Hibernate) Entity. - You would need to invoke `EntityManager.persist` (or some Spring-Data-JPA function) to make it a JPA(Hibernate) Entity.

Comment: Ok.  Fair enough.  So that begs the question ... how is Spring JPA flushing and inserting an object that I have never called save on and has an id of null?  I've also tried querying for the object before doing my insert and the query result set does not have the new object so the query is just hitting the db and not merging in any cached entries from the session.

Comment: @Scott Delap: how get Spring JPA knowelge about this object? could you please post the code that is used for creating this object.